# Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Homebrewing Stack Exchange](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [When and how should I add Maltodextrin](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11569/when-and-how-should-i-add-maltodextrin)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Lager: No fermentation, what are my choices?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11728/lager-no-fermentation-what-are-my-choices)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What are the consequences of a "weak" boil?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11778/what-are-the-consequences-of-a-weak-boil)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to use "natural" Irish moss](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11481/how-to-use-natural-irish-moss)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Will secondary further clear my IPA?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11486/will-secondary-further-clear-my-ipa)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Did I just contaminate my beer?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11601/did-i-just-contaminate-my-beer)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why is potassium metabisulphite preferred to sodium by some sources?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11607/why-is-potassium-metabisulphite-preferred-to-sodium-by-some-sources)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Do I have contamination('infection')?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11536/do-i-have-an-infection)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [When dry hopping, do you wait for clearing before bottling?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11553/when-dry-hopping-do-you-wait-for-clearing-before-bottling)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Kegging but without CO2 tank](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11620/kegging-but-without-co2-tank)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

Answer (score 2):

A bit of feedback - this self review is a bit of a difficult task on a StackExchange such as Homebrew, because many of the questions are very situational.

If someone asks a question that can be answered definitively, then it's easy to rate it. ie, 'How do you calculate ABV by a drop in specific gravity'.

However, Homebrew has a lot of other questions that are much, much harder to compare to Google. ie, 'Here's a picture of my Krausen. Does this look like an infection?'. At best, you can evaluate similar questions asked in forums and the answers, but this is much more difficult than evaluating answers to more factual questions.

Comment: If it was easy, I'd do it myself ;-) Thanks for taking the time to chime in - whether or not you think it helps, I remain confident that this is worth doing, just to stay focused on our strengths.